# Scala import statement incorrectly imports implicit value

Tags: scala

I am trying to add `~=` *operator* to `Double` in Scala. The below is my attempt:

```scala
package mypackage

object Implicits {

  case class MyEpsilon(value: Double) // Wrapper class for implicit argument

  implicit class MyDouble(val v: Double) extends AnyVal {
    /**
     * Return true if 2 doubles are approximately equal
     */
    def ~=(other: Double)(implicit epsilon: MyEpsilon): Boolean = {
      scala.math.abs(v - other) <= epsilon.value
    }

    /**
     * The same as above, but implicit value type is Double
     */
    def ~~=(other: Double)(implicit epsilon: Double): Boolean = {
      scala.math.abs(v - other) <= epsilon
    }
  }

  implicit val defaultDouble: Double = 1e-6
  implicit val defaultMyEpsilon: MyEpsilon = MyEpsilon(1e-6)

}
```

So that when we write `1.0 ~= 1.01`, Scala should implicitly convert `1.0` to `MyDouble` class, which has `~=` method.

**Question:**
But why does the following code work for `~=` without having to define an implicit value of type `MyEpsilon`?
(On the other hand, as expected, `~~=` doesn't work, because we need to define a local implicit value of type `Double`.)

```scala
import mypackage.Implicits.MyDouble // Try to import only "MyDouble" class

val a: Double = 1.0
val b: Double = 1.0 + 1e-3

val res0 = (a ~= b) // Why does this work without having to define implicit value of type "MyEpsilon"?

// Below doesn't work unless we define a local implicit value of type "Double"
// error: could not find implicit value for parameter epsilon: Double
val res1 = (a ~~= b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make an experiment in REPL:

```
@ object A {
    trait B
    object B {
      trait C
      object C {
        implicit val b: B = new B {}
      }
      implicit val c: C = new C {}
    }
  } 
defined object A

@ implicitly[A.B.C] 
res3: A.B.C = ammonite.$sess.cmd2$A$B$$anon$2@13f9ad9

@ implicitly[A.B] 
cmd4.sc:1: could not find implicit value for parameter e: ammonite.$sess.cmd2.A.B
val res4 = implicitly[A.B]
                     ^
Compilation Failed
```

We can see that:

- implicit of type `A.B.C` placed in `A.B` was found
- implicit of type `A.B` placed in `A.B.C` was not found

When Scala starts looking for implicits it works more or less like this:

- look at the current scope, are there any visible values of sought type? if so, are they annotated with implicit? (this also means that when you overshade `implicit val foo: Foo` with `val foo: Foo` implicit disappears from implicit scope)
- if there are none look at companion objects of all the types contributing to the sought type

  - e.g. if you have `Foo[(A, B[C])]`, compiler will search companion objects of: `Foo`, `Tuple2`, `A`, `B` and `C`
  - as our experiment shown nested types also count - `A.B.C` will trigger lookup in `A`, `B` and `C`

So in your case Scala would look for implicit in companions:

- in case of `MyEpsilon`: in `MyEpsilon` and in `Implicits`
- in case of `Double`: in `Double`

That's why your first example compiles and the second fails to find the implicit.